# Error TS7053 when accessing any index of the target of a React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

Basically I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/javascript-auth/), converting it to React and TypeScript

Here's the code I've written for the onSubmit event

```
const signUp = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Problematic lines of code
  const email = event.target[0].value;
  const password = event.target[1].value;
};
```

And the basic signup form

```
  return (
    <div>
      <form id="signUp" onSubmit={signUp}>
        <h3>Sign up</h3>
        <label>Email </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" />
        <label>Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
```

The full error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'EventTarget'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS7053
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be getting it incorrectly. `onSubmit` event will not contain any input values. To access the input values, I'd suggest you store them in a state and bind it using `onChange` so that when the form is submitted you can validate using the state values.

Short answer to get this working:

Add an id attribute to the input tags to access the values on submit.

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />


const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submit-demo-fjls0

Comment: Thanks! Just needed to cast the the `HTMLElement` that `document.getElementById` returns to `HTMLInputElement`